# Check if specific user is logged in - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I need to know is there's any way to check wither a specific user is currently logged in like in an admin control panel or something
I know there's

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

but that doesn't cover what I need it just checks wither the current user is not anonymous

Answer (score 0):

I actually I found a solution for it using

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser("username");
bool isLogged = user.IsOnline
```